# php implode array elements

Tags: php, arrays, string

How do I turn the following array

```
$p = array('1' => 'a', '2' => 'b', '3' => 'c');
```

into the following output? Note that each array element is on a separate line:

```
1:a 
2:b
3:c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [basic for-each construct](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$p = array('1' => 'a', '2' => 'b', '3' => 'c');
foreach($p as $key => $value) {
  echo $key.":".$value."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $colon_separated = array();
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $colon_separated[] = "$key:$value";
}
$result = implode("\n", $colon_separated);
```